# KeyError: u"FALSE [while running 'Extract label ids']"

Tags: google-cloud-ml, apache-beam

I am using the flower tutorial code in cloudml-samples trying to implement a multi-label classification on a set of restaurant photos.

I have the dict.txt and input updated accordingly and here are the sample lines.

---

### dict.txt

```
good_for_lunch
good_for_dinner
takes_reservations
outdoor_seating
restaurant_is_expensive
has_alcohol
has_table_service
ambience_is_classy
good_for_kids
```

---

### eval_set.csv

```
...
gs://yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/train_photos/312753.jpg,good_for_dinner,takes_reservations,has_alcohol,has_table_service,good_for_kids
gs://yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/train_photos/342651.jpg,good_for_lunch,good_for_dinner,outdoor_seating,good_for_kids
gs://yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/train_photos/217079.jpg,takes_reservations,has_table_service
...
```

---

Preprocess job started running fine, then I see this specific error keeps coming up, until job failed.

```
python trainer/preprocess.py \
  --input_dict "$DICT_FILE" \
  --input_path "gs://yelp_restaurant_photo_classification/labels/eval_set.csv" \
  --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval" \
  --cloud
```

[image: Snapshot of Job Logs]

---

### Job Logs - KeyError: u"FALSE [while running 'Extract label ids']"

```
(d8285fa55cb6ab07): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 514, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 894, in dataflow_worker.executor.MapTaskExecutor.execute (dataflow_worker/executor.c:24204)
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 197, in dataflow_worker.executor.ReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/executor.c:7039)
    def start(self):
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 202, in dataflow_worker.executor.ReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/executor.c:6946)
    with self.spec.source.reader() as reader:
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 212, in dataflow_worker.executor.ReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/executor.c:6891)
    self.output(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 142, in dataflow_worker.executor.Operation.output (dataflow_worker/executor.c:5249)
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 89, in dataflow_worker.executor.ConsumerSet.receive (dataflow_worker/executor.c:3487)
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 500, in dataflow_worker.executor.DoOperation.process (dataflow_worker/executor.c:14239)
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 134, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive (apache_beam/runners/common.c:4172)
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 168, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5282)
    self.reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 181, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.reraise_augmented (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5665)
    raise
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 166, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5218)
    self._process_outputs(element, self.dofn_process(self.context))
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 222, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._process_outputs (apache_beam/runners/common.c:6400)
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 89, in dataflow_worker.executor.ConsumerSet.receive (dataflow_worker/executor.c:3487)
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 500, in dataflow_worker.executor.DoOperation.process (dataflow_worker/executor.c:14239)
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 134, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive (apache_beam/runners/common.c:4172)
    self.process(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 168, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5282)
    self.reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 179, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.reraise_augmented (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5646)
    raise type(exn), args, sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 166, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5218)
    self._process_outputs(element, self.dofn_process(self.context))
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 191, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._process_outputs (apache_beam/runners/common.c:5838)
    for result in results:
  File "trainer/preprocess.py", line 130, in process
KeyError: u"FALSE [while running 'Extract label ids']"
```

---

### Job Logs - Workflow failed

```
(f3c7c09c0b6a453c): Workflow failed. Causes: (688819c5d32d79c8): S06:Read input+Parse input+Extract label ids+Read and convert to JPEG+Embed and make TFExample+Save to disk/Write to gs:__yelp_restaurant_photo_classification_yelp_restaurant_photo_classification_preproc_eval/Write/WriteImpl/write_bundles+Save to disk/Write to gs:__yelp_restaurant_photo_classification_yelp_restaurant_photo_classification_preproc_eval/Write/WriteImpl/pair+Save to disk/Write to gs:__yelp_restaurant_photo_classification_yelp_restaurant_photo_classification_preproc_eval/Write/WriteImpl/WindowInto+Save to disk/Write to gs:__yelp_restaurant_photo_classification_yelp_restaurant_photo_classification_preproc_eval/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Reify+Save to disk/Write to gs:__yelp_restaurant_photo_classification_yelp_restaurant_photo_classification_preproc_eval/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Write failed.
```

Comment: Can you provide two additional details in your post?  What environment are you running from: cloud shell, datalab docker, local machine etc?  Also are you sure all the labels in the .csv are present in dict.xt?

Comment: 1. Environment is Google Cloud Shell, with the flower example able to run end to end successfully. 2. No, I have noticed that I did not have all labels which is in the eval_set included in dict.txt, so I am re running by adding the missed label in dict.txt, to see whether the workflow can be finished. Follow up question is from the comment in the preprocess.py, my understanding was the image(s) with label(s) that not in dict.txt will be skipped, rather than expecting the error message?

Comment: Yes you're right; the comments lie.  I'll update the code  Thank you for bringing this up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a row in your input CSV file where the label is 'FALSE', but 'FALSE' is not in 'dict.txt'.

Comment: You are right, it was my bad that I did not re check the csv file, "FALSE" exists in the csv, because some of the photos in the training was not assigned any category. However, according to "When processing CSV file:
- all labels that are not present in input_dict are skipped". The FALSE supposed to be treated as a label not presented in input_dict, the row should be skipped. I am rerunning the job by adding the "FALSE" into the input_dict, to see whether the "FALSE" errors are the cause of the job failure.